# How to change matcaps using pie menus?

Tags: python, scripting

[image]I want to create a pie menu with a variety of matcaps.

On this screenshot you can see the technique im using to include "transform" function into pie menu. But it doesnt work when i try to include matcaps into pie menu. The picture at the bottom shows the desired result.